# SQL: selecting rows based on a 2-column criteria

Tags: mysql

I am wondering if there is an elegant SQL query to select rows based on a 2-column criteria.

In particular, referencing the top table below, I seek to return all rows for any 'group' in column V1 that has exactly one row of that group containing the value '1' in column V2.

```
    V1          V2          V3          V4
    ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
    group1           1           2           4
    group1           0           3           5
    group1           0           2           4
    group2           0           3           5
    group2           0           2           4
    group2           0           3           5
    group3           1           2           4
    group3           0           3           5
    group3           0           2           4
    group3           0           3           5
    group4           1           2           4
    group4           1           3           5
```

So the above data set would return

```
    V1          V2          V3          V4
    ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
    group1           1           2           4
    group1           0           3           5
    group1           0           2           4
    group3           1           2           4
    group3           0           3           5
    group3           0           2           4
    group3           0           3           5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to solve this.  But using a `JOIN`, the correct logic would be:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM t JOIN
     (SELECT v1
      FROM tablename
      GROUP BY v1
      HAVING SUM(v2 = 1) = 1
     ) tt
     ON t.v1 = tt.v1;
```

If `v2` only takes on the values 0 and 1, you could use `SUM(v2) = 1`.

The syntax `SUM(v2 = 1)` is a shorthand in MySQL.  The comparison `v2 = 1` is a boolean expression that returns true/false.  In a numeric context (such as a `SUM()`), the trues are treated as `1` and the falses as `0`.

If you just want the `v1` values where this is true, then the subquery answers that question.

Comment: I'm very proud to see that -sometimes- it happened to think in the same way :) :)  :)

Comment: Thank you Gordon. I appreciate your help on this forum, so much so I just order a new copy of Data Analysis Using SQL and Excel (2nd Ed.) which I look forward to receiving.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a nested query: Inner query to get the groups with more than one V2=1, outer query to select all records of that group:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename AS outer
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT V1
    FROM tablename
    GROUP BY V1
    HAVING COUNT(IF(V2 = 1, 1, NULL))
) AS inner ON inner.V1 = outer.V1
```

The same problem could also be solved with an EXIST() condition, but that would probably be a bit less efficient.

Comment: Thank you, and I appreciate the extra details :)

Answer (score 0):

This will also work:

```
SELECT T.* FROM TEST T JOIN (
SELECT V1, SUM(V2) AS SUMA FROM TEST
GROUP BY V1
HAVING SUM(V2) = 1
) X ON T.V1 = X.V1
```

You can see the result here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50c15/11

Comment: Thanks for your help, I also appreciate the added link!